# How can I find changes stashed on a particular date?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have stashed many changes, so I have at least 10 to 15 in my `git stash list`.

I'm looking for a particular change, but it is rather tedious to look through the contents of each one of the entries in the list.

However, I do know on what date the changes were stashed, so I was wondering if there is some way to filter the list by creation date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A stash is a special commit and `git stash list` is a shortcut for `git reflog refs/stash` and takes the same arguments

So, if you want the stash from the April 04 you can use

```
git stash list --since='Apr 04'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to manage your stash list. Maybe you should just add the date in the stash message with

```
git stash save "enter date"
```

EDIT : I thought you could custom the stash message automatically with a hook, but it doesn't seem that way eventually